# Powerapp-Create date object with fixed day,month and next year dynamically

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

My requirement is I wanted to create an date object with specific day,month and next year dynamically.

e.g. 30th April 2022. here 30 and April will be fixed ,year will get changed based on current year.

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Date, Year and Today functions in conjunctions to achieve that:

```
Date(Year(Today())+1, 4, 30)
```

If I use that on a **Label** control, it returns the following:

> April 30, 2022

You can use that in a **Date Picker** control as well